# Disabling Cache

Tags: playframework-2.0

I've got a site which is viewed after a POST request. After leaving the site with normal means, I would like to secure it so nobody could navigate back to it with a Back/Forward button.
I've added the headers Cache-Control and Pragma with no-cache params. Also i've added a  Expires header with -1 value, which also doesn't work.

Comment: Łukasz, try to improve your question... now ... ciężko zgadywać co masz na myśli

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't display any page as a result of POST request, instead use a redirect to some GET view...

It will NOT prevent you against browser's back action, anyway it will avoid re-sending request at accidental refresh.